# Show that $T$ is a linear operator - Linear Transformations in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

We are asked:

Consider the operator $T:\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ where $T(x_1, x_2) = (x_1 + kx_2, -x_2)$ for every $(x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb{R^2}$. Here $k \in \mathbb{R}$ is fixed.

a) Show that $T$ is a linear operator
b) Show that $T$ is one-to-one

We know in part (a) that a linear operator is one that satisfies the conditions of linearity

$$T(x_1 + x_2) = T(x_1) + T(x_2)$$
$$T(kx_1) = kT(x_1)$$

How do I apply that to the problem given?

We know that in part (b) a function is one-to-one whenever

$$T(x) = T(y)$$
for some $x$ and $y$ we must have $x=y$ (this is the property of 'onto').

I am almost certain that these responses are not proper solutions to my questions.

Comment: Let $x:=(x_1,x_2)$ and $y:= (y_1,y_2)$. Check $T(cx+y) = cT(x) + T(y)$. Remember a linear transformation is injective if and only if the kernel is $\{0\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ T(\vec a + \vec b) = ( a_1+b_1 + k(a_2+b_2), -(a_2 + b_2) ) = (a_1 + k a_2, -a_2) + ( b_1 + k b_2, -b_2) = T(\vec a) + T(\vec b) $$

also ..

$$T(x) = T(y) \Rightarrow x_1+k x_2 = y_1 + k y_2 \text { and } -x_2 = -y_2 $$

so $x_2 = y_2  $  and $x_1 = y_1  $ hence $x=y$ and $T$ is one to one.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

there is some confusion between componets and vectors (or points) in your notation.

For part a) you have to prove:
$$
T(\vec x+\vec y)=T(\vec x)+T(\vec y)
$$
with: $\vec x=(x_1,x_2)$ and $\vec y=(y_1,y_2)$

and 
$$
T(k \vec x)=kT(\vec x)
$$
with with: $\vec x=(x_1,x_2)$

Use the definition of T for $T \vec x$ and $T \vec y$ and you find the proof.

In the same way you can prove b).